# double/float returns 0 when multiplied

Tags: c

I have been trying to multiply the credit variables but every time i do the multiplication returns 0.

````c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char name[50];
    char apellido1[20];
    char apellido2[20];
    int age;
    float credit1;
    float credit2;
    float credit3;


    double costem1 = (credit1*15.45);
    double costem2 = (credit2*(15.45*1.25));
    double costem3 = (credit2*(15.45*1.5));

    printf("Introduzca su nombre utilizando hasta 50 carácteres\n");
    fgets(&name,sizeof name,stdin);
    printf("Introduzca sus apellidos utilizando hasta 20 carácteres por apellido\n");
    scanf("%s%s",&apellido1,&apellido2);
    printf("Introduzca su edad\n");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("Introduzca sus créditos en la matrícula\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf",&credit1,&credit2,&credit3);
    printf("%lf\n%lf\n%lf",costem1,costem2,costem3);
}```
````

Comment: `double costem1 = (credit1*15.45);` You have to read the values from the user _before_ you try to use them. When this line is run, `credit1` is uninitialized. Same with others.

Comment: Using uninitialized values means it could be anything.

Comment: You are multiplying by unitialized values. What result do you expect?

Comment: If your compiler doesn't shout at you then you need to enable more warnings. The `scanf` format `%lf` is for the type `double`, not `float`. On that note, unless you have very specific requirements you should not use `float`. Use `double` for all your floating point values and variables.

Comment: Normally, if you use `%lf` in a `printf()` format, it emphasizes that the values printed are `double` variables.  Since default argument promotion rules mean that `float` values are passed to `printf()` et al. as `double` values, there isn't a problem technically, but the messaging is not as clear as it should be.  With `scanf()` et al., it is crucial to use `%lf` with `double *` values and `%f` with `float *` values.  The `%lf` for `printf()` was added in C99 for symmetry with `scanf()` — it wasn't strictly necessary — and using `%f` is equivalent to `%lf` for `printf()` (but not `scanf()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float credit1;
float credit2;
float credit3;


double costem1 = (credit1*15.45);
double costem2 = (credit2*(15.45*1.25));
double costem3 = (credit2*(15.45*1.5));

...

scanf("%lf%lf%lf",&credit1,&credit2,&credit3);
printf("%lf\n%lf\n%lf",costem1,costem2,costem3);
```

This doesn't work the way you think it does -- `costem1`, `costem2`, and `costem3` don't store *formulas*, they store the *values* of the expressions `credit1 * 15.45`, `credit2 * (15.45 * 1.25)`, etc., using whatever value is currently stored in the `credit*` variables.

At this point in the program's execution, `credit1`, `credit2`, and `credit3` have not been initialized or assigned so their initial value can be *anything*, including `0.0`.

You have to assign values to each of the `credit*` variables *before* you can use them to compute any of the `costem*` variables:

```
/**
 * Prefer double over float unless you have a 
 * really good reason not to.
 */
double credit1, credit2, credit3;
...
scanf( "%lf %lf %lf", &credit1, &credit2, &credit3 );
...
double costem1 = credit1 * 15.45;
double costem2 = credit2 * 15.54 * 1.25;
...
```

Also, any time you find yourself declaring multiple variables of the same type with the same name and an ordinal or cardinal number (`credit1`, `credit2`, `credit3`), that's a real strong hint you want to use an *array*:

```
double credit[3];
...
scanf( "%lf %lf %lf", &credit[0], &credit[1], &credit[2] );
```

Comment: It's worth noting that in C there are "formulas" in the form of *functions*, as in `float costem1(float credit1)` where that can do the required computation, though it will only do it if *called*. I think a lot of people with a math background assume a lot of things happen for you by definition, when in C few things ever happen without explicitly being called. That is C code defines a *procedure*, not *rules*.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized credit1, credit2 and credit3.

This way they can have the value "0". When you do the multiplication by zero, you will have zero.

Comment: The *can* have the value 0, but they could actually be anything.